# TFS2010 - capture unittest execution time in team build

Tags: benchmarking, tfsbuild

It is possible to 'capture' or persist the time it takes per unittest, when running a team build on TFS2010. Ideally saving it to database (like a loadtest can save it to a result store).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Visual Studio unit tests during build, you can choose to publish the test results to the server, then later you can query the test run and results to find out the duration of each test result.

The code to query the test results per build looks like this:

```
        var tcmService = TeamProjectCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
        var tcmProject = tcmService.GetTeamProject(TeamProjectName);
        ITestRun testRun = tcmProject.TestRuns.ByBuild(BuildUri).First();
        ITestCaseResultCollection results = testRun.QueryResults();
        foreach (ITestResult result in results) { Console.WriteLine(result.Duration); }
```

You will need to obtain the team project collection, know the team project name and the build uri. This code assumes that your build has only one published test run, though that sometimes is not true because you can publish other test runs to the same build after it is completed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Follow up question - In regards to a team build, do I need to invoke mstest manually from MSBuild or can I set it up another way?

Comment: Sicne you're using TFS 2010, there is already an activity called RunTests that will find the test assemblies in your binaries and run the tests for you. By default running tests is enabled for build definitions.

Comment: Lots of resources online on how to do this, I'm sure MSDN should have some details as well: http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2009/06/03/tfs-team-build-2010-running-unit-tests.aspx

Comment: Might not have been clear about my question. We are already running unittests by setting the RunTest node and everything. My question is how to setup where to publish the result. Do I need to invoke mstest.exe (using a <exec> tasks) manually or can I set the publish parameters up another way. Not we do not use WF yet.

Comment: Oh so you're using the upgrade template? Hm... you would need to call mstest to publish the test results (do mstest /? for more details). You can do this as a build task, I guess. For the default template of 2010 the activity RunTests does it for you by default.

Comment: Ok - just making sure. Thanks